# Правильное сохранение даты

Tags: c#, unity3d, дата, datetime

возникла проблема с сохранением даты. Генерирую дату, путем добавления к текущей дате и времени двух минут. после перезапуска программы дата не сохраняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;



public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timenow;
    public Text time;
    public DateTime timerSob;
    private Save da = new Save();

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("da"))
        {
            da = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("da"));
            timerSob = da.timerSob;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timenow.text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
        time.text = Convert.ToString(timerSob);
    }

   public  void timer()
    {
        timerSob = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
    }

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR                                 //ПРОЦЕСС СОХРАНЕНИЯ ДАННЫХ ИГРЫ
    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        if (pause)
       {               
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("da", JsonUtility.ToJson(da));
        da.timerSob = timerSob;
       }  

    }

#else
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {

        da.timerSob = timerSob;

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("da", JsonUtility.ToJson(da));
    }
#endif 


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Save
    {        
        public System.DateTime timerSob;
    }
}
```

Comment: Требуется сохранить дату?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для загрузки используйте:

```
time = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Time"))
```

Для сохранения:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Time", time.ToString());
```

И в коде работайте с переменной *time*, тип которой *DateTime*.

Comment: спасибо, помогло